# How to map POST request bodies into various field (NODE.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, post

I have some Code that looks like this:

```
let myStackObject = {
            $set: {
                genericMongoFieldName: {
                    A: platter.A,
                    B: platter.B,
                    C: platter.C,
                    D: platter.D,
                    E: platter.E,
                    F: platter.F,
                    G: platter.G
                }
            }
        };
```

I want to know if the mapping can be done in a better more efficient way?
What if the request body contains thousands of fields?
Please note the mapping is in a complex object, i'm only trying to edit values in fields inside a field so ObjectName(req.body) is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its looks like

```
...
```

is your friend,
you can use

```
...platter
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is `genericMongofieldName: {...platter}` correct syntax? I can't seem to get it working

Comment: Yes, it is the correct syntax, you can read more about spread syntax on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax